# Remove tailing characters

Tags: tcl

Please tell me way to remove `=` and newline character `\n` from the end of string which is embedded between <>.

For example input string

```
set string "abcd  1234   abc=
"
```

i just want to remove = and new line from end

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove all `=` and newlines from the end, no matter how much there are, I suggest `string trimright`

```
set string "abcd  1234   abc=
"
string trimright $string =\n
set str2 "abc===="
string trimright $str2 =\n ; returns abc
```

If you know that the last 2 characters are `=\n`, you can also use string range

```
string range $string 0 end-2
```

For more complex solutions, regexp is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `regsub`

```
regsub {=\n$} $string {} string
```

**Test**

```
% set string "abcd  1234   abc=
"
abcd  1234   abc=

% regsub {=\n$} $string {} string
1
% puts $string
abcd  1234   abc
```